# Axios with React gives 200 (304 in network tab), but gives junk HTML response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I seem to be missing a key piece here. Any ideas?

```
    componentDidMount(){this.retrieveConfig();} 


    retrieveConfig = () => {const { locnNbr } = this.props.data;
    axios.get(`/some/uri/stuff`).then(res => 
        {console.log('retrieveConfig res', res);
        this.setState({config: res. data});
        });
    };
```

Comment: Sorry for formatting. Mobile.

Comment: What is the response you're getting?

Comment: And here is the response:

{
  "data": "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\n<head>\n  <!-- The first thing in any HTML file should be the charset -->\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\n  <!-- Make the page mobile compatible -->\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\n  <!-- Allow installing the app to the homescreen -->\

Comment: Try adding a ```/``` before your request URL, i.e. ```/configuration-service/configuration...```

Comment: Looks like you're `.get`ting a page. If you go to the URL you're `.get`ting in a browser, do you get a page back?

Comment: Tried adding '/' but same result

Comment: I can't hit it directly in a browser because I'm being routed to the app login.  It works fine in postman though.

Comment: can you provide the exact url? mobile ios/android?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you're getting back in Postman?

Comment: Can’t provide the exact url. It’s work related.

Comment: Postman:

[
    {
        "updatedOn": "2019-10-04 17:49:52 UTC",
        "createdOn": "2019-07-09 22:52:44 UTC",
        "version": 130,
        "enabled": 1,
        "id": 59,
        "locnNbr": 7221,
        "appName": "offpricedc",
        "moduleName": "handheld",
        "configKey": "PackawayActivityTypes",
        "configValue": "[{\"activityType\":\"PALLETPULL\",\"processArea\":\"BLK\",\"activityTypeDesc\":\"Pallet Pull Bulk area\",\"mode\":\"Pallet\",\"dropLocation\":\"PT01A001\",\"binMessage\":\"N\",\"systemDrivenSubstitute\":\"NA\",\"countBins\":\"NA ...}

Comment: on which mobile?

Comment: In the incorrect HTML response you're getting, is there any indication to what the page is? Text nodes, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount = () => {
 this.retrieveConfig();
};

retrieveConfig = () => {
  Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I'm getting res.json() is not a function

Comment: And also removed the res.json(). Axios doesn't require it.

Comment: Check the console. https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-hawking-lyfjy.

Comment: the space is a formatting issue on this website.  That space is not in the code.  The console gives a 304 in the network tab

Comment: https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/304-not-modified 
304 should be a server sided error

Comment: can you share the api?

Answer (score 0):

Html response you got only for mobile and it will work from postman because the url you are trying to hit from server mobile will not able to hit. So you add the cer to your mobile.

public certificate of server where as postman allows it but mobile does not allow to hit all server urls

Comment: This does not make sense. Can you please provide clarification on your response?

Comment: yes. from mobile we can't hit all endpoints which are in server specially this happens  with company servers they might have use the certificates so you need public cer need to be add into your mobile so it can hit the endpoints.

Comment: I believe there was a misunderstanding - the OP was posting that he was on mobile because he's using StackOverflow on mobile, not that he's experiencing the issue specifically from a mobile browser. @Accribus can you confirm?

Comment: confirmed: I'm not using a mobile browser to test.  I'm apologizing for posting this question from my phone with subpar formatting in the post

Comment: This is for both mobile and browser you need to add cer into your laptop or mobile if you are trying to hit server endpoints.only there is no issues with endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Consider double checking your URLs.

I'm assuming you're trying to reach a REST API endpoint but you're getting a web page as your response, which for me would suggest you're hitting the wrong port on the right domain. I believe Axios defaults to using port 8080 (web default), and it's unlikely your API is running on that port. So make sure you're specifying your URL like:

```
Axios.get("http://sub.domain.com:123/endpoint").then...
```

If you could share which URL you're using in browser and in Postman that might give more information on what's going on differently there.

The 200/304 thing makes sense from that perspective as well. It's a 200 since the request went fine but Chrome is caching the request for that web page and it's reporting that it hasn't changed (that's what 304 means).

Comment: Or could it be that your request isn't authenticated, if it's the same port the endpoint handler might route you to login if you're not authenticated properly?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I come across this issue in Firefox Developer Edition and I have not figured out why this happens (I believe it has to do with the response headers).

I manage to fix it every time by clearing the browser's cache.